# How did North America became Panem?

Tags: the-hunger-games

I think this has happen by some natural disasters like storms, droughts, fires, encroaching, and the seas taking over our land.

Comment: The polar ice caps melted, covering the Earth with water...no, wait, wrong film.

Comment: It's unknown. http://thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/Panem